# How do I use CSS with a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

How do I use CSS with RoR? When I link externally, I'm never able to see the files. I cp'd the .css file to every folder I could think of...views, controller, template, and nothing seems to work.

What do I need to do to enable external CSS files with a rails application? I'm new to rails, so forgive me if this is basic.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Put the CSS files in public/stylesheets and then use:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "filename" %>
```

to link to the stylesheet in your layouts or erb files in your views.

Similarly you put images in public/images and javascript files in public/javascripts.

Comment: there is no "public/stylesheets" where can I add my file?

Comment: Then you can create it add the public folder in the same directory as your app folder. Then add a stylesheets folder within the public folder.

Comment: The link tag needs to be in the head part of my document, correct?   If I only need the style in one erb partial, is there a way I can conditionally add it when that partial is needed?  Or is there a way I can add if the current route matches a specific one?

Comment: @JulienLamarche tad bit late, but I would look into the `content_for` method. There is an example further down in section 3.5 Using Nested Layouts. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

Answer (score 30):

If you are using rails > 3 version, then there is a concept called `asset pipeline`. You could add your CSS to

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```

then it will automatically be picked up by the app. (this is useful as rails will automatically compress the CSS files)

[read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) about the asset pipeline

Comment: That's `app/assets/stylesheets` (should be 's' on 'assets')

Answer (score 16):

Use the rails style sheet tag to link your main.css like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
```

Go to

```
config/initializers/assets.rb
```

Once inside the `assets.rb` add the following code snippet just below the `Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.css )
```

Restart your server.

Comment: This is the correct (more specific) answer per Rails documentation. You must add it to the assets.rb for precompile!

Answer (score 14):

I did the following...

1. place your css file in the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder.
2. Add the stylesheet link `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "filename" %>` in your default layouts file (most likely `application.html.erb`)

I recommend this over using your public folder. You can also reference the stylesheet inline, such as in your index page.

Comment: This is not working for me, giving AssetsFilter error

Answer (score 4):

The original post might have been true back in 2009, but now it is actually incorrect now, and no linking is even required for the stylesheet as I see mentioned in some of the other responses.  Rails will now do this for you by default.

- Place any new sheet .css (or other) in app/assets/stylesheets
- Test your server with rails-root/scripts/rails server and you'll see the link is added by rails itself.

You can test this with a path in your browser like testserverpath:3000/assets/filename_to_test.css?body=1

Comment: Sorry to necropost, but you are just as guilty as I. However, this is not the case at all. If you want to utilize the asset pipeline, and you have properly linked your CSS file in your application.html.haml (or .erb) your server will throw an error, and tell you to add it to the precompile (config/initializers/assets.rb) sorta like so `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )`

Answer (score 3):

With Rails 6.0.0, create your "stylesheet.css" stylesheet at **app/assets/stylesheets**.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above, the most obvious place to add stylesheet_link_tag is in your global application layout - application.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in your public folder? Whenever I have images or the like that I need to reference externally, I put it all there.