# Using CSS inside Rails 3.2.13

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

Checked out some links, but it seems that people who answer assume a little bit more than I know.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and I need to add some styling to my Views.

I have the assets/stylesheets/trade_page.css. What steps do I have to take, where do I have to reference it, what line do I put inside the View pages to use this styling?

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/how-do-i-use-css-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: You're right, I didn't read far enough into the answers. The solution for my version was a little lower.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) documentation. You will need to require the file within your `application.css` file (if you are not already requiring the whole tree) and then the most common place is to include the `application.css` file using a `stylesheet__link_tag` in the `application.html.erb` file