# How do I add CSS to Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out how to add CSS to my Ruby On Rails code.

This is my index.html.erb file where I attempt to include the stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "app\assets\stylesheets\welcome.scss" %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome To Dot</h1>
        <p>Make Life Easier</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside of the assets\stylesheets folder I have a welcome.scss file:

```
h1{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: darkgoldenrod;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The body shows up but does not have any styling.

application.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track'       => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

When leave it as default, I do not see any CSS in my code.  When I change it to application, i get the error.

Comment: Remove app/assets. from the stylesheet link tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use CSS with a ruby on rails application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/how-do-i-use-css-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application)

Comment: Now I am getting: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index. When I search for this problem it tells me to change my application.html file and make the parameters 'default' but I've already done that.

Comment: do you have `application` files in your app?  `application.html.erb` etc.

Comment: @IgorIvancha Yes I have an application file.  I'll add it to the question

Comment: show, please, your `default.css`

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome" %>
```

Please consider going through the Rails guides on the [Asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) that elaborate on using asset helpers to include assets in HTML page.

Comment: Now I am getting: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index.  When I search for this problem it tells me to change my application.html file and make the parameters 'default' but I've already done that.

Comment: Please post a full backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` to the layouts/application.html.erb file. You don't have to put to any other file css tags. Yield do the job. application.html.erb loaded to any view of your app.

Comment: When I changed 'default' to 'application' I get ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Comment: Do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete your stylesheet tag on your `index.html.erb` and in your `application.html.erb` 
Have a stylesheet link tag like this : `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. 
-- if that doesn't help , you should check what is written after `application/default <filename>.css`
Scss must not be written for now..
`<filename>.scss`
That worked for me