# How do I allow .scss to reach html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

What is the equivelant of this in ruby on rails? I have installed bootstrap but my scss files are not reaching my html.erb files.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use CSS with a ruby on rails application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/how-do-i-use-css-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application)

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :mystyle %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, as we're not seeing how you have your stylesheets configured for your app, but I know there's some pretty specific (though somewhat awkward to locate) directions for establishing SCSS with Bootstrap within the GitHub documentation. Give this a shot (if you haven't already):

Import Bootstrap styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

```
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or import before bootstrap itself.
@import "bootstrap";
```

Make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it:

```
$ mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

Then, remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements from the Sass file. Instead, use `@import` to import Sass files.

Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins and variables.

This was all located here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

I don't follow the instruction to remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements... I just leave them, but when adding your `@import` statements within your application.scss file (once it's renamed), be sure to have

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

@import "bootstrap";
```

listed in that order with the file.

Comment: Oh... and my link tag for locating SCSS files is then:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

(auto-generated that way, when I establish my Rails project the way I do)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I have bootstrap working nicely, however, when I attempt to edit my scss (to change colours of all <h2> headings for example), it simply does not work.