# application.scss does not stylize the input, textarea, select

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby on rails with railstutorial.org and i have problem with listing 7.15 / 7.16 
Soo.. 
this is repo 
[repo](https://github.com/Mroczeks/first_project)

If i add styles in application.css to form_for in users/new.html.erb i have this 
[image]

We see that custom.css does not stylize the input, textarea, select
users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

How fix it?

Comment: Please write what you tried and more detail about the problem, also change the title of this.

Comment: I think the problem is because you are not adding your custom.scss to your application.css. Ideally, you should convert your application.css to application.scss (sass) and then import the custom.scss in there.

You are only including the application.css in your layout file and so your custom.css is not being loaded

Comment: But before adding styles to the form, everything worked so I do not know if it will help

Answer (score 0):

I think your custom css file in not loaded. Use following steps:

Put the CSS files in public/stylesheets and then use:

to link to the stylesheet in your layouts or erb files in your views.

Comment: You can check in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/how-do-i-use-css-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application