# How to add stylesheets in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am referencing stylesheets in my index.html.erb file as below

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/CSS/External/bootstrap.min.css" %>
```

I have my folder structure as

```
apps\assests\stylesheets\CSS\Internal
```

and

```
apps\assests\stylesheets\CSS\External
```

But in page, it is rendering as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/CSS/External/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also, I see that my files are rendering twice as attached image

[image]

and I get the following errors

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use CSS with a ruby on rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/how-do-i-use-css-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application)

Comment: You must read this carefully http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline for basic asset pipeline

Comment: Can you just give me a simple example with works with the structure that I have provided as per my comments

Also, as I said, I see two times that the files are being loaded

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need this line in `index.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/CSS/External/bootstrap.min.css" %>
```

because it's included globally into `layouts/application.html.erb` something like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

For JS

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

This will mapping automatically from `assets` folder.

If your folder structure like this `stylesheets/CSS/External` then opens your `application.css`  and add like this

```
 *= require CSS/External/bootstrap.min
```

after `*= require_tree .`

You can use [`Bootstrap Ruby Gem`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) for bootstrap styling, it's simple & easy to implementation based on there doc

**Update**

For example, the directories are `assets/stylesheets/css/external` and the `css` file are inside this directory like

```
assets/stylesheets/css/external/
...............................bootstrap.css
...............................other.css
```

and your `assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require css/external/bootstrap
*= require css/external/other
*= require_self
*/
```

Comment: Hi fool-dev
As per your suggestion, I have added all my CSS files in `application.css` and removed all my CSS references from index.html.erb file

But still I dont see references of those files in my html file

Comment: See this repo for reference [here](https://github.com/shabbir-ahmed/todo-app-with-ruby-on-rails-5/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets)

Comment: You just put `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.css` into `assets/stylesheets` folder and do nothing, see what's happening and leave `application.css` as before

Comment: If I place all of my CSS files in stylesheet folder and add its corresponding entries in assest.rb, then it is working fine.

But, If I wan to use my folder structure as mentioned above, how do i do that?